# How can i get the size of a folder in Firemonkey?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I want to calculate the size of a folder in android. I have tried this

```
function GetDirSize(dir: string; subdir: Boolean): Longint;
var
  rec: TSearchRec;
  found: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  if dir[Length(dir)] <> '\' then dir := dir + '\';
  found := FindFirst(dir + '*.*', faAnyFile, rec);
  while found = 0 do
  begin
    Inc(Result, rec.Size);
    if (rec.Attr and faDirectory > 0) and (rec.Name[1] <> '.') 
    and (subdir = True) then
      Inc(Result, GetDirSize(dir + rec.Name, True));
    found := FindNext(rec);
  end;
  FindClose(rec);
end;
```

This is giving incorrect size in android but giving correct size in windows Platform.Is there any other way to findout the size for android?

Comment: Do some debugging. This is a skill that you should acquire. Why is the output incorrect. Pick a directory, and log the steps that the function takes. Use that to deduce what is incorrect. Certainly `'*.*'` looks odd. Surely you mean `'*'`. It's not idiomatic to test `b = True`. Test `b` instead. Also, `rec.Attr and faDirectory > 0` looks odd, why not `rec.Attr and faDirectory <> 0`?

Comment: The other thing that is probably going to burn you is that surely on Android your code uses zero based strings. You likely want to switch to zero based strings on all targets for simplicity. Anyway, the advice about debugging stands. If you can't debug, you'll be forever stuck. Take the time to learn how to debug.

Comment: David is correct. So you should use `IncludeTrailingBackslash` method (http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.SysUtils.IncludeTrailingBackslash) for making sure there is always a trailing backslash presen in your directory string

Comment: And `rec.Name[1]` is wrong too - use `rec.Name[low(rec.Name)]` I guess. But please please please learn some debugging.

Comment: Your code is wrong for Android. Android uses `/` for the path separator, not `\`, and doesn't use `*.*` for file masks (because it's not Windows). And rather than use `if dir[Length(dir)] <> '\'` (which works fine if you're only running on Windows), use either `IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter` or `TPath.Combine`.